# JSF : How put onfocus, onblur effect in input field?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I'm thinking about how can I implement `onfocus` and `onblur` effects in my input field in JSF 2.0.

[image: Example in HTML]

I do the following in HTML:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="Name (required)"
   onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'Name (required)'; }"
   onfocus="if (this.value == 'Name (required)') {this.value = ''; }"
   class="text-input" />
```

Now I'm wondering how I could do this in JSF 2.0. Does anyone have an idea?

**EDIT**

I'm trying the attribute 'onblur' and 'onfocus' but still nothing appearing in my input field.

```html
<h:inputText onblur="Nome" onfocus="" ></h:inputText>
```

Comment: The same attributes are supported in most JSF components. Just use them and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the same attributes as your HTML sample. The following piece of code works just fine:

```html
<h:inputText id="name" value="Name (required)"
   onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'Name (required)'; }"
   onfocus="if (this.value == 'Name (required)') {this.value = ''; }" />
```

Comment: i would like to use my controller here, so in value attribute stay this way value="#{contact.client.name}", not value="Name (required)", understand ?

Comment: @Valter: You can do that yes. And you could initialize the value in your backing bean.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`onblur`](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/h/inputText.html) attribute of `<h:inputtext>`

Comment: i try what you suggest but still not applying the effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a view source on the rendered html page, does it show the html that you are looking for? - If so you are good to go or atleast it is working as designed :-). Basically whatever jsf h: type tags that you have should be rendered as equivalent html.